# actual code in static method or instance method

Tags: java, static

I'm writing a small library.

```java
public class MyClass {

    public static String doSomethingWithString(final String s) {
        new MyClass().doSomething(s);
    }

    public String doSomething(final String s) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or I can do like this.

```java
public class MyClass {

    public static String doSomethingWithString(final String s) {
        return null;
    }

    public String doSomething(final String s) {
        return doSomethingWithString(s);
    }
}
```

Which style is preferable? Are they same?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for comments and answers.

Here are two classes.

```java
public class IdEncoder {

    private static String block(final long decoded) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(decoded));
        builder.append(Integer.toString(
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(9) + 1)); // 1-9
        builder.append(Integer.toString(
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(9) + 1)); // 1-9
        builder.reverse();
        return Long.toString(
            Long.parseLong(builder.toString()), Character.MAX_RADIX);
    }

    public static String encodeLong(final long decoded) {
        return block(decoded >>> 0x20) + "-" + block(decoded & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
    }

    public String encode(final long decoded) {
        return encodeLong(decoded);
    }
}
```

And another style.

```java
public class IdDecoder {

    public static long decodeLong(final String encoded) {
        return new IdDecoder().decode(encoded);
    }

    public long decode(final String encoded) {
        final int index = encoded.indexOf('-');
        if (index == -1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong encoded: " + encoded);
        }
        return (block(encoded.substring(0, index)) << 32)
               | (block(encoded.substring(index + 1)));
    }

    private long block(final String encoded) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(
            Long.toString(Long.parseLong(encoded, Character.MAX_RADIX)));
        builder.reverse();
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        return Long.parseLong(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? and why?

Comment: This code doesn't do anything, so it's hard to give useful advice...

Comment: I'm just curious. I'm currently doing first style. I wonder changing to second style can make some possible impact or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just picking between these 2 options, take the second one.

The reason is the first requires you to allocate a new dummy object on the heap just to call a method.  If there is truly no other difference, don't waste the time and space and just call the static method from the class.

The second is more akin to a static Utility function, which are a fine coding practice.

Comment: The disadvantage to static utility methods is they make it difficult to extend the behavior.  Certainly in some cases this is what is intended, but worth considering the possibility that users of your class may want to expand upon the behavior you've defined.  In such a case, instance methods are superior.

Comment: I won't disagree.  There are definitely many times to use instance methods(probably most times).  In this case though there is probably not a need since it instantiates a default object just to call something that obviously can be static.

Answer (score 2):

When writing a library, ease of use dramatically trumps general best practices.  Your method should be static if it doesn't make sense for a user to instantiate something in order to access it.  However often it is actually much cleaner and more powerful for a method to be part of an object, because it allows the user (as well as the library writer) to override it in child classes.

In a sense, you aren't actually asking a programming question, but a UX question.  Ask yourself how your users would best benefit from accessing your code, and implement it that way.  As a good benchmark, look at the [Guava API](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/); it consists of many static utility classes, but just as many classes and interfaces designed to be easily extended.  Do what you think is best.